# Mysql insert query to be fixed

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this mysql query insert query which giviing the below mentioned error and i am not able to figure why

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('edinburgh', 'edinburgh*glasgow' ,'Loreum ipsim'), VALUES ('newcastle',  ' at line 3

```
INSERT INTO wp_widget_custom (name,centers,description)     
VALUES ('glasgow',  'glasgow*edinburgh' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('edinburgh',    'edinburgh*glasgow' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('newcastle',    'newcastle*middles-brough'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('leeds',    'leeds' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('manchester',   'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('nottingham',   'nottinghamshire*lichfield' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('lichfield',    'lichfield*birmingham*nottinghamshire'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('birmingham',   'lichfield*birmingham*milton-keynes'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('milton-keynes',    'milton-keynes*hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('cardiff',  'cardiff*bristol-international' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('bristol',  'bristol-international*bristol*cardiff' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('plymouth', 'plymouth'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('southampton',  'southampton*hemel-hempstead*reading*maidenhead*slough' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('reading',  'hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire*reading*maidenhead*slough*guildford' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('slough',   'surrey*hertfordshire*hemel-hempstead*reading'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('hemel-hempstead',  'slough*surrey*guildford*bromley*london*billericay*hertfordshire*hemel' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('london',   'hempstead*maidenhead'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('crawley',  'crawley*bromley*guildford*surrey*london'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('bromley',  'billericay*crawley*london*billiericay*bromley' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('upminster',    'crawley'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('billericay',   'billericay*london*bromley' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('livingston',   'edinburgh*glasgow' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('renfrewshire', 'edinburgh*glasgow' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('northumberland',   'newcastle' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('west-yorkshire',   'leeds' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('cheshire', 'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('nottinghamshire',  'nottinghamshire'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('staffordshire',    'lichfield*birmingham*nottinghamshire'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('warwickshire', 'milton-keynes*birmingham'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('northamptonshire', 'milton-keynes' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('south-gloucestershire',    'bristol-international*bristol*cardiff' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('north-somerset',   'bristol*bristol-international*cardiff' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('devon',    'plymouth'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('hampshire',    'southampton*guildford*surrey*reading*maidenhead*slough'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('berkshire',    'southampton*maidenhead*reading*slough*surrey'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('maidenhead',   'guildford*hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('surrey',   'surrey*guildford*reading*slough'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('sussex',   'bromley*crawley'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('kent', 'crawley'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('essex',    'bromley*sittingbourne*london*london*billericay*bromley'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('hertfordshire',    'hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire*slough*milton-keynes*maidenhead*slough'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('buckinghamshire',  'hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('oxfordshire',  'milton-keynes' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('leicestershire',   'lichfield*nottinghamshire' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('derbyshire',   'nottinghamshire*lichfield' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('portsmouth',   'southampton'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('gloucester',   'bristol*milton-keynes*birmingham*lichfield'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('coventry', 'nottinghamshire'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('stoke-on-trent',   'manchester*lichfield*nottinghamshire'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('bolton',   'manchester*leeds'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('huddersfield', 'leeds' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('liverpool',    'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('merseyside',   'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('leicester',    'birmingham*nottinghamshire'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('bradford', 'leeds' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('wolverhampton',    'birmingham*lichfield*nottinghamshire'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('dudley',   'birmingham*lichfield*nottinghamshire*hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire*slough' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('luton',    'maidenhead'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('preston',  'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('sunderland',   'newcastle*middlesbrough*birmingham*lichfield*nottinghamshire'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('walsall',  'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('swansea',  'cardiff'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('norfolk',  'thetford-forest'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('norwich',  'thetford-forest'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
VALUES ('hull', 'hull'  ,'Loreum ipsim');
enter code here
```

Comment: You only need to specify `VALUES` once.  Just remove all the other occurrences of that keyword.

Comment: brother i want all to be inserted through 1 query

Comment: Like I said, just remove all the other occurrences of that keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO wp_widget_custom (name,centers,description) VALUES     
('glasgow',  'glasgow*edinburgh' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('edinburgh',    'edinburgh*glasgow' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('newcastle',    'newcastle*middles-brough'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('leeds',    'leeds' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('manchester',   'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('nottingham',   'nottinghamshire*lichfield' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('lichfield',    'lichfield*birmingham*nottinghamshire'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('birmingham',   'lichfield*birmingham*milton-keynes'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('milton-keynes',    'milton-keynes*hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('cardiff',  'cardiff*bristol-international' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('bristol',  'bristol-international*bristol*cardiff' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('plymouth', 'plymouth'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('southampton',  'southampton*hemel-hempstead*reading*maidenhead*slough' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('reading',  'hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire*reading*maidenhead*slough*guildford' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('slough',   'surrey*hertfordshire*hemel-hempstead*reading'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('hemel-hempstead',  'slough*surrey*guildford*bromley*london*billericay*hertfordshire*hemel' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('london',   'hempstead*maidenhead'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('crawley',  'crawley*bromley*guildford*surrey*london'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('bromley',  'billericay*crawley*london*billiericay*bromley' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('upminster',    'crawley'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('billericay',   'billericay*london*bromley' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('livingston',   'edinburgh*glasgow' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('renfrewshire', 'edinburgh*glasgow' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('northumberland',   'newcastle' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('west-yorkshire',   'leeds' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('cheshire', 'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('nottinghamshire',  'nottinghamshire'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('staffordshire',    'lichfield*birmingham*nottinghamshire'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('warwickshire', 'milton-keynes*birmingham'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('northamptonshire', 'milton-keynes' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('south-gloucestershire',    'bristol-international*bristol*cardiff' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('north-somerset',   'bristol*bristol-international*cardiff' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('devon',    'plymouth'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('hampshire',    'southampton*guildford*surrey*reading*maidenhead*slough'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('berkshire',    'southampton*maidenhead*reading*slough*surrey'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('maidenhead',   'guildford*hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('surrey',   'surrey*guildford*reading*slough'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('sussex',   'bromley*crawley'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('kent', 'crawley'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('essex',    'bromley*sittingbourne*london*london*billericay*bromley'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('hertfordshire',    'hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire*slough*milton-keynes*maidenhead*slough'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('buckinghamshire',  'hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('oxfordshire',  'milton-keynes' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('leicestershire',   'lichfield*nottinghamshire' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('derbyshire',   'nottinghamshire*lichfield' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('portsmouth',   'southampton'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('gloucester',   'bristol*milton-keynes*birmingham*lichfield'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('coventry', 'nottinghamshire'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('stoke-on-trent',   'manchester*lichfield*nottinghamshire'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('bolton',   'manchester*leeds'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('huddersfield', 'leeds' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('liverpool',    'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('merseyside',   'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('leicester',    'birmingham*nottinghamshire'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('bradford', 'leeds' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('wolverhampton',    'birmingham*lichfield*nottinghamshire'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('dudley',   'birmingham*lichfield*nottinghamshire*hemel-hempstead*hertfordshire*slough' ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('luton',    'maidenhead'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('preston',  'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('sunderland',   'newcastle*middlesbrough*birmingham*lichfield*nottinghamshire'  ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('walsall',  'manchester'    ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('swansea',  'cardiff'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('norfolk',  'thetford-forest'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('norwich',  'thetford-forest'   ,'Loreum ipsim'),
('hull', 'hull'  ,'Loreum ipsim');
```

Answer (score 3):

Just have one `VALUES`:

```
Insert into table (..) VALUES (...),(...),...
```

Do not repeat the `VALUES` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to repeat the word VALUES.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/insert.html

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas.
>
> Example:    INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);